# Time Machine won't back-up to external hard drive, any way to fix this?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, disk-utility, ssd

**Problem**

When I try to make a back-up using time machine, the back-up gets to about ~500 MB and than halts. The following error is given:

> An error occurred while copying files. The problem may be temporary. If the problem persists, use Disk Utility to repair your backup disk.

I've already repaired the disk several times, so I believe that is not the problem. The errors given by console for "backupd" are -

> Copy stage failed with error:11
>
> Backup failed with error 11: 11

Another error message also popped up several times, from the process "TMHelperAgent" -

> Month 13 is out of bounds

**Specs**

I'm using a 2016 MacBook Pro, running MacOS High Sierra (version 10.13.2). The hard disk I'm backing up to is a Samsung 1TB SSD, partitioned into two volumes (one for data, one for the backup).

Comment: In re: `Month 13` error. There's a [bug in macOS](https://robservatory.com/month-13-is-out-of-bounds/).